# convert: no decode delegate for this image format `JPEG' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/509

Tags: imagemagick

I am not able to change resolution of the image. I am using following command but every time NoDecodeDelegate exception is being thrown.
I used following command:

convert -units PixelsPerInch c:/images/test1.jpg -density 132 c:/images/test1imgdensity.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close, but you need `-set` to change the density of an existing image:

```
convert -units PixelsPerInch -size 200x100 xc:red -set density 256 result.jpg
```